# html dropdown option background color issue in chrome Browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-3, google-chrome

I have web based application in MVC4 which having a drop down with 302 records.
On drop down item selection I have set color like Gray.
But that Gray color will spread in whole Drop down including option tag too.

Here, is my css class

```
select
{
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #717171;
    color: #fff;
}
.toolbar select > option
{
    background-color: #fff !important;
    color: #000;
}

.toolbarDropdownSelected
{
    background-color: #8B5052 !important;
}
```

Till, 300 records everything is look good in Chrome browser but if records are exceed than 300 then Gray color spread in whole Dropdown including options in case of Chrome Browser.

In Firefox browser everything is look good if records are exceed than 300.

I have attached screenshot. Please have a look.
[image]

Expected result should be like below image which is result from Firefox
[image]

Please check this link in Chrome Browser. I have version 44.0.2403.107 m of Chrome Browser https://jsfiddle.net/gk30zj0k/

Please help.

Comment: Can you post your HTML code instead of image?

Comment: Please check this link in Chrome Browser. I have version 44.0.2403.107 m of Chrome Browser

https://jsfiddle.net/gk30zj0k/

Comment: Indeed a problem with Chrome browser. Can you file a bug?

Comment: Means ?
Can you see the issue with that share link ?
If there are 300 records in Drop down, in that case it's work good in Chrome.
You can check manually edit the code from shared link.

Comment: Yes, you can report this bug to the [Chrome team](http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines). I am seeing the same issue here, after 300 records.

Comment: Yes. I have reported to Chrome team. Will you please up my question so people come to know about this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome developers thought nobody would put more than 300 items in a select dropdown so to improve performance they turned off css styling if you exceeded it. After much uproar they are removing that restriction in v45.
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=513339

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on chrome as well Try this one

```
select, select:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
  color: #fff;
}

option {
  color: #000;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Sorry it's not working in Chrome Browser if there are 300+ records in drop down.

Comment: I tried for 370 options it is working may be some css is conflicting in your case

Comment: Thanks Sneha for efforts but it's not working in Chrome Browser.
I have check you link in Chrome Browser
I have version  44.0.2403.107 m of Chrome Browser

Comment: Please update Chrome and let me know this issue should occur